# Get number of elements after using np.unique Python

Tags: python, numpy, size, unique

I e got a set of elemnt. the task is to get the number of unique elements. I wrote the following:

```
 import numpy as np
 tokens1 = set(["a", "b", "c", "c"])
 print(np.unique(tokens1))
 print(np.unique(tokens1).size)
```

The result is

```
[{'c', 'b', 'a'}]
1
```

How do i get the correct number  - 3?
Should have i simply used something other than np.unique in the first place?
there might be a better way to get hat i want.

Comment: do you notice that you're returning a set within a list, hence the size is returning 1

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy i see the problem but i still dont know how to get the size. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So, what exactly is the input? Is it the set or the list of `["a", "b", "c", "c"]`?

Comment: am I missing something or is `len` no good here? `len(np.unique(tokens1)[0])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the number of unique elements in a set, you can simply call `len()` on the set. To modify your existing code:

```
tokens1 = set(["a", "b", "c", "c"])
print(len(tokens1))
# prints: 3
```

This is because a set already removes duplicates. You don't need to use both a set AND `np.unique()`.

If you wanted to use `np.unique()` instead, you could modify your code to be:

```
tokens1 = np.unique(["a", "b", "c", "c"])
print(len(tokens1))
# prints: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set), sets are the unordered collection of unique elements so the line `np.unique(tokens1)` is redundant. You should use `len(tokens1)` instead.